# Different definitions of abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Í'm writing some notes about homological algebra and I started to ponder about two different definitions of abelian categories.

1. A category is abelian if it's preabelian, every monomorphism is a kernel and every epimorphism is a cokernel (somewhat the standard definition nowadays);
2. A category is abelian if it's preabelian and, for every morphism $f$, the natural map $\operatorname{coim}f\to\operatorname{im}f$ is an isomorphism. (Grothendieck's definition.)

I know how to prove that they are equivalent but I would like to understand better the pedagogical advantages of each one.

I see two main points: it is (way) easier to prove that $(2)\implies (1)$ than it is to prove that $(1)\implies (2)$ but using approach (1) we can prove early-on that $\ker(\operatorname{coker})$ satisfies the universal property of images, which motivates better the notion of image than simply defining as being $\ker(\operatorname{coker})$. (Or is it *obvious* that this should be the definition of the image?)

I would like to know what the community here thinks about whether it is better to start with either definition and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what's more standard, but I personnally usually see 2 being used, and I like it better because the intuition behind it is clearer (essentially you're imposing some form of "first isomorphism theorem")

The fact that $\ker(\mathrm{coker})$ is the image is intuitively obvious if you view $\mathrm{coker}$ as being, well $B/\mathrm{im}(f)$ : the kernel of the projection is (or at least should be) $\mathrm{im}(f)$.

With a bit of thought, you can also see why (1) makes intuitive sense, but 2 just seems more intuitive, at least to me.

But that's just a personal point of view. In fact, I think for abelian categories, you soon forget the definition (or at least I do), and mostly you work with them with "everything you can"

Comment: I think I agree with you, even though I think the universal property of images is still more intuitive than $\ker(\operatorname{coker})$. I will leave this question open for a little more time since I would love to hear other opinions. Thank you for your answer!